# Set Gravity to TextView with background drawable image programmatically not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I search for this problem but i didn't find a convenient answer.
I try to add dynamically a TextView to a LinearLayout, but the problem is that the setGravity doesn't work.
This is my code:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                textView.setText(colorKeyword(resources.getString(R.string.tipsbutton_tooltip)));
                textView.setTextSize(35);
                textView.setTextScaleX(1.1f);
                textView.setPadding(textViewPadding, textViewPadding, 0, textViewPadding);
                textView.setTextAppearance(mContext, R.style.fontForTooltipsTexts);
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                textView.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tip_box);

                tooltipView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                ImageView arrowView = new ImageView(mContext);
                arrowView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tip_arrow_down);
                arrowView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                arrowView.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                tooltipView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                tooltipView.addView(textView);
                tooltipView.addView(arrowView);
```

If i set the layout height of the textview to MATCH_PARENT, the gravity knows to center the text horizontal as i need, but the side effect is that all the background/ textview area is stretched to the parent height.
I now for sure is a problem related to the order in which they are laid out. Is probably something that i miss to do.

I use this for parent:

```
LinearLayout tooltipView = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        tooltipView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        tooltipView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tooltipView.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        tooltipView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

I tried to inflate from a layout in which i already added the background, but i have the same problem.

The height of the TextView should match to the background image height.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `setGravity` works as expected, use hierarchyviewer to see your view bounds and you will make sure it works ok

Comment: try to give Gravity.CENTER instead of Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL to see any effect which might help to get the issue

Comment: I suspect you misunderstand how LayoutParams work. The parent ViewGroup provides it's version of LayoutParams for its child Views. Say you want to center a TextView in a LinearLayout. **1.** Create a `LinearLayout` and a `TextView`. **2.** Create `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER)`. **3.** `linearLayout.add(textView, layoutParams)`.